# Trig substitutions

Tags: integration, book-recommendation

What is the name of a textbook where one could find a good overview of trig substitutions for integration.
I currently own Apostol's Vol. 1 & 2 and Vol. 2 doesn't touch them and Vol 1 is almost silent on the topic.

Would Spivak's Calculus go over them? Any help would be amazing.

Comment: You don't need a book.  You do a trig substitution if $1)$ you have $x^2 \pm a^2$ (possibly having to factor something out first to get it in that form) occuring somewhere is your integrand and $2)$ you can see a trig sub will make your integral easier (i.e. something will cancel).  If both of those conditions are satisfied -- and you don't notice an easier method -- then use a trig sub.

Comment: [This site](http://calculus.seas.upenn.edu/?n=Main.TrigonometricSubstitution) tells you which identity you're using when performing a trig sub.  That might make it a little easier for you to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a book, wikipedia has a nice list of all kinds of integrals, also for trigonometric identities:
[List of integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_integrals)

Comment: I wouldn't consider linking to an integral table an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please find a complete list of trig substitutions with great details on Math Range [section 1.3](http://mathrange.com/trigonometric-substitutions/)